# Remove spinning ball when hidden application start

Tags: c++, windows, spinning

I have created a program in c++ that doesn't have any GUI. When this program stars windows shown a spinning ball for about 5 seconds.

Is there any way to remove this?

Comment: you mean your application is showing it ? or is it wait cursor from windows?

Comment: Windows shows this spinning ball, some kind of processing indication..

Comment: How do you start that program?

Comment: I think a screen shot would be really helpful in this question :)

Comment: Interesting. Mac OS X uses a spinning ball for a wait cursor (actually, it uses for the application-not-responding-to-messages cursor). Any chance someone who wishes they had a Mac has customized your Windows installation?

Comment: Well yeah! They call it Windows 7.. =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not completely sure, but I think it goes away if you create a top-level window. Most Windows applications intended to run from the GUI, should create a top-level window, even if they aren't intending to make it visible (Don't call ShowWindow ).

Also, you probably want to recieve some types of notifications which Windows sends to top-level windows (at least a close command when the user logs off etc).

And at some point, you'll probably want to install a notification icon, I think it's necessary to have a top-level window for the tray notification area to work (at least it was when I last used this interface in 1996).

I think anything intended to run from the GUI should create a window, even if it's an invisible one.

Comment: Thank's for your respond, it worked perfectly! I did a CreateWindowEx, the ball disappeared after a call to GetMessage.